# Database query and get_user_meta return incorrect data

Tags: loop, ajax

I have a PHP script that gets details from a checkbox and a text field. The console.log data is correct and so is the updated data in the database, however, when I try and get the data, using $wpdb or get_user_meta(), I receive incorrect data (i receive previously updated data, even though in the database te data is different).

**Here's my code:**

//Form

```
<form id="donations" method="POST" >
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
      $option = get_the_title();
      $id = get_the_ID();
    ?>
    <input type="radio" class="charity" id="charity-<?php echo $id ?>" name="charity" value="<?php echo $id ?>" <?php if ($_POST[$id] == $id) echo 'checked'; ?> >
    <label for="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></label>
    <br>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  <div class="more-don--wrapper">
    <label for="more_donation">The standard card cost is R50.00. <br>Enter a different amount below if you would like to donate more (must be more than R50.00).</label>
    <input type="number" min="60" step="10" placeholder="50.00" id="more_donation" name="more_donation" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['more-donation'])){ echo $_POST['more-donation']; }else{ echo '50'; } ?>"/>
    <span class="more_donation_tc">All additional amount will go directly to the nominated charity.</span>
  </div>
  <!--<input class="button" type="submit" value="Update Selection" />-->
</form>
```

//Ajax script

```
jQuery( 'document' ).ready( function( $ ) {

  // Form submission listener
  //$( '#donations' ).submit( function() {
  $('.choose-charity').click(function() {

      // Grab our post meta value
      var charity = $( '#donations .charity:checked' ).val();
      var more_donation = $( '#donations #more_donation' ).val();

      // Do very simple value validation
      //if( $( '#donations #charity #donation' ).val().length ) {

          $.ajax( {
            url : ajax_url,                   // Use our localized variable that holds the AJAX URL
            type: 'POST',                     // Declare our ajax submission method ( GET or POST )
            data: {                           // This is our data object
                action: 'um_donation',        // AJAX POST Action
                'charity': charity,           // Replace `um_key` with your user_meta key name
                'more_donation': more_donation,
            }
          })
          .success( function( results ) {
            console.log( 'User Meta Updated! ' + charity + ' ' + more_donation );
          })
          .fail( function( data ) {
            console.log( data.responseText );
            console.log( 'Request failed: ' + data.statusText );
          });

      //} else {
          // Show user error message.
      //}

      return false;   // Stop our form from submitting

  });

});
```

// Data update script

```
function donations_callback() {

    // Ensure we have the data we need to continue
    if( ! isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

            // If we don't - return custom error message and exit
            header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Empty POST Values' );
            echo 'Could Not Verify POST Values.';
            exit;
            
    }

    $user_id        = get_current_user_id();                            // Get our current user ID
    $charity        = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['charity'] );             // Sanitize our user meta value
    $more_donation  = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['more_donation'] );   // Sanitize our user email field

    if( !empty($charity) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'charity', $charity );                  // Update our user meta
    }else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'charity', '' );    
    }

    if( !empty($more_donation) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'more_donation', $more_donation );          // Update our user meta
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'more_donation', '' );
    }

    //update_field('charity', $charity, 'user_'.$user_id.'');
    //update_field('more_donation', $more_donation, 'user_'.$user_id.'');

    exit;

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_um_donation', 'donations_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_um_donation', 'donations_callback' );
```

And this is my loop in a tabular form. The first tab is where the form (above) is and the last tab is where I retrieve the data and the code is as follows:

```
<?php
  // get saves meta values (charity and amount)
  /*
  $charity_id = esc_html( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'charity' , true ) );
  $charity = get_the_title( $charity_id );
  $donation_amount = esc_html( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'more_donation' , true ) );
  */
  global $wpdb;

  // get charity id
  $charity_meta_key = "charity";
  $charity_id = $wpdb->get_var( 
      $wpdb->prepare( 
          "SELECT meta_value 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE user_id = %d 
          AND meta_key = %s",
          $user_id,
          $charity_meta_key
      ) 
  );

  // get charity name
  $charity = get_the_title( $charity_id );

  // get donation amount
  $donation_meta_key = "more_donation";
  $donation_amount_db = $wpdb->get_var( 
      $wpdb->prepare( 
          "SELECT meta_value 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE user_id = %d 
          AND meta_key = %s",
          $user_id,
          $donation_meta_key
      ) 
  );
  $donation_amount = $donation_amount_db;
?>
```

The commented out get_user_meta returns the same output as the $wpdb. How would I go about solving my issue - it is a cache issue? Any point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab you where you Displayed the data doesn't refresh after the Ajax call. Refresh the page in your ajax sucess call back to get the proper results.

Comment: Thank you @pradipta-sarkar – that has solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome @TheLovableType